# Transferir arquivos por FTP para Hospedagem Java

Tags: java-ee, ftp, hospedagem

Se eu contratar um host para hospedar minha aplicação Java posso transferir arquivos por `ftp`? para que essa minha aplicação realize a leitura desses arquivos?

Tenho uma aplicação desktop que fica no servidor que gera um arquivo `.xml` a cada 1 hora e tenho uma aplicação web que lê esses arquivos. Porém como normas de segurança da empresa não posso fazer conexão direta entre o sistema web e o servidor, me falaram que uma forma mais segura de realizar esse processo é passar esses arquivos `.xml` por ftp para que o sistema web possa lê-los. Isto é possível?

Comment: FTP não seria uma boa escolha para questões de segurança, o ideal seria então SFTP ou melhor ainda se for [SCP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/343723/2766598). Também não entendi a aplicação é Desktop porém roda no servidor, como seria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Você deve configurar o serviço de ftp em um servidor.

Do lado do seu cliente Desktop você deve fazer upload do arquivo para o servidor ftp utilizando uma das muitas bibliotecas para isso (e.g., [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) da biblioteca [Apache Commons Net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)).

Do lado do servidor você pode, entre outras estratégias, ter processos batch schedulados para ler esses arquivos. O Java EE 7 possuí uma [API dedicada para processamento batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/batch-processing.htm#GKJIQ6), temos também o bom e velho [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/).

---

**PS:** Normas da companhia são normas da companhia, porém lembre-se que usar FTP não torna a transferência de arquivos automaticamente segura... Um SFTP bem configurado é uma alternativa interessante a um serviço de upload https, mas de uma maneira ou de outra será necessário controlar aspectos como autenticação / autorização / auditoria, etc. Disponibilidade também é um desafio independentemente do protocolo escolhido (veja as [8 falácias da computação distribuída](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing)).

De uma maneira ou de outra transferir arquivos de maneira segura, barata e confiável não é fácil... Não é a toa que em pleno século XXI ainda temos [VANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_network) e serviços de [EDI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDI) sendo cobrados por kilobyte.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou estudar essas bibliotecas e com o tempo ir aprimorando esse sistema